# Formulario javascript a json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy tratando de pasar toda la información del formulario a través de `JavaScript` y convertirla a `JSON`. Hasta ahora lo hace, el problema es que no pone todo junto como quiero estructurarlo.

Por ejemplo este es el elemento que me imprime

```
{"items":[[{"foods":"breakfast"}],{"food":"milk"}]}
```

Y realmente cómo lo quiero es así

```
{"items":[{"foods":[{"breakfast":[{"name":"milk"},{"name":"colacao"}]}],"snack":[{"name":"bread"},{"name":"marmalade"}]}]}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#preview").click(function() {
    var comidas = {
      items: []
    };
    $(".xboxfood").each(function() {
      var allcomidas = [{
        comida: $(this).find(".comidaname").val()
      }];
      comidas.items.push(allcomidas);
      $(".fieldwrapper").each(function() {
        var allalimentos = {
          alimento: $(this).find(".alimento").val()
        };
        comidas.items.push(allalimentos);
      });
      //console.log("COMIDA: " + comida + "\nALIMENTO: " + alimentos);
    });
    $("#console").text(JSON.stringify(comidas)); // strigify to show
  });
});
var countFoods = 0;
var countAliment = 0;

function deleteFood(id) {
  var boxdelete = document.getElementById(id);
  boxdelete.remove();
  //countFoods--;
}

function deleteAliment(id) {
  var alimentdelete = document.getElementById(id);
  alimentdelete.remove();
  //countAliment--;
}

function addAliment(id) {
  countAliment++;
  var newaliment = document.getElementById(id);
  div = document.createElement("tr");
  div.className = "fieldwrapper";
  div.id = "deleteAliment" + countAliment + "";
  div.innerHTML =
    '<tr class="fieldwrapper" id="deleteAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '">' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="quantityAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="100"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="alimento Alimentsname" name="nameAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" type="type" placeholder="Alimento ' +
    countAliment +
    '"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="caloriesAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="proteinAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="carbsAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="fatsAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input class="Alimentsnumber" name="fiberAliment' +
    countAliment +
    '" step="1" min="0" type="number" value="0"></td>' +
    "<td><a onclick='deleteAliment(\"deleteAliment" +
    countAliment +
    '");\' class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #f44336 red z-depth-0"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></td>' +
    "</tr>";
  newaliment.appendChild(div);
}

function addFood() {
  countAliment++;
  countFoods++;
  //var newfood = document.getElementById("newfood");
  var newfood = document.getElementById("newfood"),
    div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "boxfood" + countFoods + "";
  div.innerHTML =
    '<div style="background: rgb(0 0 255 / 5%);" class="xboxfood input-field col s12 m12">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="input-field col s10 m10" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' +
    '<input id="comida' +
    countFoods +
    '" type="text" class="comidaname validate">' +
    '<label for="comida' +
    countFoods +
    '">Nombre de comida</label>' +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="input-field col s1 m1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' +
    "<a onclick='deleteFood(\"boxfood" +
    countFoods +
    '");\' class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #f44336 red z-depth-0"><i class="material-icons center">delete</i></a>' +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="input-field col s1 m1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' +
    "<a onclick='addAliment(\"newaliment" +
    countFoods +
    '");\' class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small default-background z-depth-0"><i class="material-icons center">add</i></a>' +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="input-field col s12 m12" style="margin-top: 0px;">' +
    '<table class="striped centered responsive-table">' +
    "<thead>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<th>Cantidad (g)</th>" +
    "<th>Alimento</th>" +
    "<th>Calorías (kcal)</th>" +
    "<th>Proteínas (g)</th>" +
    "<th>Carbs (g)</th>" +
    "<th>Grasas (g)</th>" +
    "<th>Fibra (g)</th>" +
    "<th>#</th>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</thead>" +
    '<tbody id="newaliment' +
    countFoods +
    '">' +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";
  newfood.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#console {
  background: #c5c5c5;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://codetech.es/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-l2">
      <div id="newfood"></div>
      <center>
        <a id="preview" class="btn default-background z-depth-0">Prev</a>
        <a onclick="addFood();" class="btn default-background z-depth-0">Añadir nueva comida</a>

        <div id='console'></div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**[Aquí](https://codepen.io/zerocrazy/pen/zYoNdLd)** está el CodePen como lo tengo programado.

A ver si me puedes ayudar... se los agradecería mil `<3`

Comment: Hola como va? podrías por favor  pasar el como estas obteniendo esa data o de donde viene y que haces para formatearla de es manera? Todo con un ejemplo mínimo y verificable por favor.

Comment: Está todo en el [codepen](https://codepen.io/zerocrazy/pen/zYoNdLd), puedes ingresar ahí y mirarlo...

Comment: Tienes que poner el código aquí, no en sitios externos. Y, si quieres un JSON con todo el formulario podrías usar `FormData` o `serializeArray()`